# Issue creating amazon aws s3 pre signed url PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm trying to  generate a pre signed url request with the S3 PHP SDK like this:

```
$cmd = self::$S3Client->getCommand('GetObject', array('Bucket' => USER_CONTENT_BUCKET_NAME,'Key'    => $key));

$request = self::$S3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');
```

`*USER_CONTENT_BUCKET_NAME` is the bucket name defined in constants.php
`*$key` is string key.

If I `var_dump($cmd)` I can see the object is returned correctly from the `getCommand()`.

But from the `createPresignedRequest()` call, I get an exception-

```
"Argument 2 passed to Guzzle\Service\Client::getCommand() must be of the type array, object given".
```

Help?

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved.

Was rather hard to catch, as the error message did not help at understanding the underlining issue.

[This discussion helped a lot.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519693/creating-amazon-aws-s3-pre-signed-url-php)

Amazon describe in their 3.x PHP api, that the way to create pre signed urls, is the way I tried above.

However, it turns out we are using version 2.8 of the Amazon aws.
In this case, the call should be like this:

`$cmd = self::$S3Client->getCommand('GetObject', array('Bucket' => USER_CONTENT_BUCKET_NAME,'Key'    => $key));`

`$presignedUrl = $cmd->createPresignedUrl('+20 minutes');`

The Guzzle exception thrown was a symptom of the fact that the method I was calling did not exist.

I hope this will help other stuck in the same situation.